# No HDMI audio on Intel NUC Kit NUC5i7RYH with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, hdmi, intel-nuc

I find so many web posts on the topic of HDMI audio issues for intel NUC and Ubuntu, but I anyway can't get my issue fixed with any of the instructions I found.

First of all I find below info on Intel's Linux support page for NUC:
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/000005499.html
In the Troubleshooting section I find specific instructions to fix the HDMI audio issue, and I followed these instructions.

As opposed to Intel's instructions I also figured out that the correct ALSA daily package for 16.04 can be found here:
https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages

Next I installed Pulse Audio Control:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio

Here can see that e.g. youtube is sending audio, and I can choose from several HDMI output options. But all HDMI audio outputs options are shown as "unplugged" although the cable is connected and the video signal gets through. I am using a Sony multimedia receiver as my sink.

Can you please help me with instructions for troubleshooting?
Which logs do I need to pull for further analysis?

Thank you very much.

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an odd set of steps to follow, however I found the following to work each and every time on my i7/7th Gen NUC from MicroCenter, where sound worked throught the headphone jack, but not through HDMI.  Only thing is...I don't have a clue as to WHY it works.

Note:

Read this before doing it. Write down the steps so you can get back to the desktop.

Steps:

1. Open up Youtube.com to any video, so that you will hear sound when it comes back on.
2. Enter TTYL Terminal by simultaneously pressing the keys Ctrl+Alt+F1
3. Exit TTYL Terminal by simultaneously pressing hitting the keys Ctrl+Alt+F7
4. The sound should be working now.

Background:

I originally found this solution (AFTER HOURS OF RESEARCH) by accident because I needed to enter the TTYL terminal to initially set my root user's password without restarting.  As soon as I logged in as my user (before resetting any passwords) the sound randomly started working. Eventually, I found that simply entering TTYL terminal and returning to the desktop while audio SHOULD be playing caused it to work as expected ... UNTIL RESTARTING.

SO,

This solution ONLY works for the current session.  If your computer restarts for any reason, you will have to again perform this action.

If you find any other information on this, including a more permanent fix, please inform so that everyone can act on it!

Thanks,

Joseph